# What are Kusala roots?

Tags: karma, rebirth, terminology

What are Kusala roots, how are they determined, what effects do they have? And where in the Buddha's teaching are they mentioned? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'three poisons', or three 'unwholesome roots' (*akusala-mūla*), are named as ignorance, attachment, and aversion — and [the "wholesome roots" are their opposites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_poisons_(Buddhism)#Opposite_wholesome_qualities):

> ### Opposite wholesome qualities
>
> The three wholesome mental factors that are identified as the opposites of the three poisons are:
>
> - amoha (non-bewilderment); prajna (wisdom)
> - alobha (non-attachment)
> - adveṣa (non-aggression, lack of hatred); mettā (loving-kindness)
>
> The principal aim of the Buddhist path is to cultivate these and related positive qualities.

They're mentioned in for example, the [Sammaditthi Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.009.ntbb.html#kusala):

> 7. "And what is the root of the wholesome? Non-greed is a root of the wholesome; non-hate is a root of the wholesome; non-delusion is a root of the wholesome. This is called the root of the wholesome.